# How can I remove the XcodeColors dependancy from XCGLogger?

Tags: carthage, xcglogger, xcodecolor

With the latest updates to Xcode 8 when I try and do a Carthage update I'm getting the following:

*xcodebuild[9502:2418269] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID 8A66E736-A720-4B3C-92F1-33D9962C69DF for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/XcodeColors.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs*

which causes the build to fail.

How do I remove this dependency and continue to use XCGLogger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really an XCGLogger issue, it's just Xcode trying to load the XcodeColors plug-in and it not being listed as compatible. You have a couple of options to resolve this.

1. Delete the plug-in by deleting the `~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/XcodeColors.xcplugin` file.
2. Edit the `~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/XcodeColors.xcplugin/Contents/Info.plist` file and add `8A66E736-A720-4B3C-92F1-33D9962C69DF` to the list of `DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs`.

Normally Xcode 8 won't even try and load the plug-in unless you've altered Xcode 8 to do so. So option 2 above is probably your best option. Xcode will then load the plug-in and you'll have full colour in your logs again!

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I didn't alter xcode 8 to install plugins. my problem was legacy plugins, and swift tried to load them anyway when I was running a simple script. option 1 above worked fine and is the right solution.

Comment: Both options, 1 and 2 are right for different people. Personally, I love full colour in my logs, so I have unsigned Xcode and use option 2 to keep all my plug-ins working.